# How to make Laravel migrator work with namespaced migrations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I namespaced my whole package successfully but I can not get namespaced migrations to work. In the autoload_classmap.php the migration classes are nicely namespaced, but the Migrator is not looking for the migration classes within the namespace. How to get the migrator to search for the migrations within the namespace?

The migration file

```
<?php namespace Atomend\Aeuser;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Schema, User;

class UsersTable extends Migration {

   public function up() {
      Schema::create("users", function(Blueprint $table) {

         $table
            ->increments("id");
```

autoload_classmap.php

```
'Atomend\\Aeuser\\UsersTable' => $baseDir . '/src/migrations/2014_04_21_184359_users_table.php',
```

Terminal error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'UsersTable' not found in
```

This is logical since the UsersTable is in the `Atomend\Aeuser` namespace.

Issuing the migration

```
php artisan migrate --bench="atomend/aeuser"`
```

So to be clear, when losing the namespace everything works fine and dandy.

Comment: How did you create your migration file?

Comment: Can you include your command for executing the migration? is your work still on the workbench?

Comment: Did you try using the `--path` ? `php artisan migrate --path=app/foo/migrations`

Comment: did you try to run `composer dump-autoload` on the workbench root and the laravel root folders?

Comment: That doesn't work, also there is nothing wrong with the autoload_classmap.php. As you can see in the sample code it's in the proper namespace.

Comment: If you are working with HFS+ or ext3 filesystem, you can put the namespace in the name of the file, look for: https://github.com/girotecnics/geonames/tree/master/src/database/migrations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Laravel migrator doesn't play nice with namespaced migrations. Your best bet in this case is to subclass and substitute the Migrator class, like Christopher Pitt explains in his blog post: https://medium.com/laravel-4/6e75f99cdb0.

Comment: Hey Antionio, nice to get some feedback on this topic! I will have a look at your suggestion, maybe a nice feature for a pull request.

Comment: Obviously a late addition, but I discovered that Christopher Pitt's article was short a couple of details that threw me off, and I've posted what was missing in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855793/subclassing-migrator-not-working-for-namespaced-migration)

Answer (score 0):

add "Database\Migrations\": "database/migrations/" to composer.json -> autoload:psr-4